# Merging data of common keys in a same array

Tags: php, arrays

so I have an array like this :-

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = array("country" => "Netherlands", "city" => "Amsterdam");
$headers[] = array("country" => "Netherlands", "city" => "Tillsburg");
$headers[] = array("country" => "Sweden", "city" => "Stockholm");
```

I need it like :-

```
array("country" => "Netherlands", "city" => "Amsterdam,Tillsburg");
array("country" => "Sweden", "city" => "Stockholm");
```

How do I merge the values?

Here's what I have tried till now, but it doesn't seems to be working.

```
function merge($headers) {
    $final = [];
    foreach($headers as $current) {
        if(!in_array($current['country'], $final)) {
            $final[] = $current['country'];
        }
  }

  foreach($headers as $current) {
      $final[$current['country']]['city'] = $current['city'];
  }
  return $final;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Match two arrays on key value (like mysql join)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354209/php-match-two-arrays-on-key-value-like-mysql-join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use country values as temporary associative keys to determine if concatenation is necessary.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/e66pM))

```
$headers[] = array("country" => "Netherlands", "city" => "Amsterdam");
$headers[] = array("country" => "Netherlands", "city" => "Tillsburg");
$headers[] = array("country" => "Sweden", "city" => "Stockholm");

foreach ($headers as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['country']])) {
        $result[$row['country']] = $row; // store the whole row
    } else {
        $result[$row['country']]['city'] .= ",{$row['city']}";  // concatenate
    }
}

var_export(array_values($result)); // reindex the output array
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'country' => 'Netherlands',
    'city' => 'Amsterdam,Tillsburg',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'country' => 'Sweden',
    'city' => 'Stockholm',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the best solution, but I test it, it works.

```
function merge($headers) {
    $final = array();
    foreach ($headers as $current) {
        if( !isset( $final[ $current['country'] ] ) ) {
            $final[$current['country']] = [
                'country' => $current['country'],
                'city'    => $current['city']
            ];
            continue;
      }
      $final[ $current['country'] ]['city'] = $final[ $current['country'] ]['city'] . ', ' . $current['city'];
    }

    return $final;
}
```

Output

```
array(2) { ["Netherlands"]=> array(2) { ["country"]=> string(11) "Netherlands" ["city"]=> string(20) "Amsterdam, Tillsburg" } ["Sweden"]=> array(2) { ["country"]=> string(6) "Sweden" ["city"]=> string(9) "Stockholm" } }
```

You can clear keys of result array if you want adding

```
$final = array_values($final);
```

before `return` statement

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f138ff7fa9e9ad50db7a2355eaefc8d4f5f30b6)

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f138ff7fa9e9ad50db7a2355eaefc8d4f5f30b6

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = array("country" => "Netherlands", "city" => "Amsterdam");
$headers[] = array("country" => "Netherlands", "city" => "Tillsburg");
$headers[] = array("country" => "Sweden", "city" => "Stockholm");
$result = array();

foreach($headers as $key => $value) {
    $result[$value['country']][] = $value['city'];
}
$finalArray = array();
foreach($result as $k => $v) {
    $finalArray[] = array('country' => $k, 'city' => join(',', $v));
}
```

Comment: Two loops is not optimal design.

Answer (score -1):

Create another array with country name as key

```
<?php
$headers = array();
$headers[] = array("country" => "Netherlands", "city" => "Amsterdam");
$headers[] = array("country" => "Netherlands", "city" => "Tillsburg");
$headers[] = array("country" => "Sweden", "city" => "Stockholm");
$countries = array_unique(array_column($headers,"country"));

$newHeaders = array();
foreach($headers as $header){
    $newHeaders[$header["country"]]["city"][] = $header["city"];
}
print_r($newHeaders);

foreach($newHeaders as $key=>$headers){
    echo $key." City : ".implode(",",$headers['city'])."\n";
}
?>
```

Live Demo [Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b0e5a6af21c568f17d6c21c309fb47fd53a787b0)

Output would be like

```
Netherlands City : Amsterdam,Tillsburg
Sweden City : Stockholm
```